# Using String Alloy

Tags: alloy

I have an Alloy module

```
module WorkPlace

sig String{}

sig person{}

sig Employee extends person{

name :String, boss: Employee,worker: set Employee}

sig Employee1 extends person{

name :String, boss: Employee,worker: set Employee}


fact Employee{

all e1:Employee, e2:Employee| (e1.name = e2 && e2.name = e1) =>e1 = e2}

run{}
```

when i triad to run this mode it give me this massage :
"Syntax error at line 2 column 5:
There are 3 possible tokens that can appear here:
NAME seq this "

I don't know what its mean?

2\ If I have 2 Alloy models ,each model has same element i.e mode1/name, model2/name. how can I create a fact or pred which can say mode1/name = model2/name?

regards

Comment: "String" is a reserved word.  Use "string" instead (or, better, "Name").

Answer (score 1):

1. As user1513683 already answered:

   > "String" is a reserved word. Use "string" instead (or, better, "Name")
2. You can open an existing module from another module, and then in that module you can use all sigs/relations present in any of the two modules.  For example:

module 1 (file m1.als):

```
module m1

sig S1 {}
```

module 2 (file m2.als):

```
module m2

open m1

sig S2 {}

run { #S1 = #S2 }
```

Comment: Thanks guys for answering . in my first question I meant how can I use reserved words "String" in my model to compare two elements as mentioned above . the problems is when i execute the mode the analyser give me this massage : "Syntax error at line 2 column 5: There are 3 possible tokens that can appear here: NAME seq this "

Comment: You can't use "String" as a name of a sig in your model, you'll have to use a different name for it.